# Need to Deploy MVC App to production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created an Web API application using EF code first which I want to deploy it to production.

I want to move it to production, so how should I share my MVC App with client & also in production how we will be creating databases as there would be no visual studio present there
(usually in local when we run the project in VS database gets generated if we are using code first)

Comment: Could you explain maybe a bit better where you are going to deploy your application? Will it be a cloud service (Azure, AppHarbor, etc.) or a standard hosting, or a private server?

Normally, you should have an access to the database and you can connect to it through VS or SQL Management Studio.

Comment: For my testing purpose I deployed my API's in azure. But Client will be hosting this API in their server. I have a confusion reg. how I am going to share my mvc App, suppose they dont have VS & if I package it & share it to them how they will be hosting in IIS ? & also in future if I need to add a new column in database how I will be doing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use for the exact same scenario Entity Framework Migrations.
It works without any problems.

You can easily change the database from version to version.
Also downgrading is supported.
With some third party tools you can also add other dbms then SQL Server.

See http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application for some more information.